Git thinks branches have not been merged when they have
I'm trying to tidy up my local repo by deleting branches I no longer need.
I started by listing my merged merge requests in GitLab. Then I displayed the first one, got its branch name, and attempted to delete that branch in my local repo.
First, auto-complete did not work. I entered the whole branch name...
$ git branch -d <branchname>

...and got the message:
error: the branch '<branchname>' is not fully merged.
If you are sure... run 'git branch -D <branchname>'.

Well, I think I'm sure. But if GitLab says the branch is merged, why does Git say it's not?
There's probably some nifty Git command for deleting merged branches all at once, but it's not going to work as long as Git thinks that branches haven't been merged when they have!

How did you merge in Gitlab? Did you use the "squash" option maybe? This would have the effect of your changes being merged but the branch itself not and your local Git cannot know that. Look at the "graph" view in Gitlab, it might help understand.

Also, did you fetch changes from the remote first to update your local copy?

Take a look at remote branches.

The message means that the branch isn't merged to the branch you are currently on. Unless you are on your latest version of develop/main/master/whatever this doesn't necessarily mean there is a problem.

First run git fetch --all, this command will update your local repository with all the information from the remotes.
After that, if you are merging all the code to one branch, you can switch to that branch by typing git switch <branch_name> and check which branches are merged by typing git branch --merged and then proceed to delete them with the command you wrote.
If you are merging to multiple branches you can continue and try to delete desired branches. You can also switch to all those branches 1 by 1, and check which branches are merged into them as described in upper paragraph.

Nope, that's not what git fetch --all means.

I know what git fetch --all means. It collects data from all the remotes. I don't know the setup of the project and didn't want to make any assumptions.
I'm not aware of a single downside of running that command, even if there is only one remote.
Can you please state what is wrong with that command?

Personally I don't like checking out local copies of shared branches, but in a similar manner, one could do as you suggested, but in detached mode: git switch --detach <branch_name>. Nowadays after I complete a PR/MR I run a local script to detach and then delete my current branch.

I asked the same thing (you probably can't see it because I deleted my question).
Basically you'd need to update your local branch by saying e.g.
git fetch origin mybranch:mybranch

But you are unlikely to want to say that, so in my opinion it's better just to say git branch -D mybranch once you know it's merged on the remote. Saying git fetch lists the deleted branches so I always just watch that list and delete the local version of any deleted branches that are mine (using -D). It would be nice to automate this, but I can't be bothered.
